# Server.sendmail() sets my recipient as a BCC

Tags: python-3.x, smtp

I am trying to send an email to a specific recipient using python, but my code keeps setting the recipient as a BCC. How do I change this to set it as a normal To?

Thanks!

Here is my code

```
import smtplib


def send_email(subject, msg):
    login = "My_email"
    password = "password"
    reciever = "recipient@gmail.com"
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(login, password)
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail(login, reciever, message)
        server.quit()
        print("Success: Email sent!")
    except:
        print("Email failed to send.")

subject = "Test email"
Sensor_Message = "This has worked"
send_email(subject, Sensor_Message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know python, but here is what I think the problem is: your message does not contain a To: or Cc: email header containing the recipient's email address.

Because the recipient's email address is in the list of RCPT TO commands sent over SMTP, but not in the email headers, the recipient's MUA (e.g. Gmail, Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.) treats it as a Bcc.

To fix this problem, make sure that the message contains a To: or Cc: header for the recipient.

Unrelated nitpick: the correct spelling is "receiver"

Good luck!